# Updating a tkinter progress bar in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, progress-bar

I'm new to python development and have had some issues with finding resources on this issue. I am trying to create a progress bar that opens up in its own gui. I've heard that the best way to do this is to use tkinter however all the resources I've found that explain how to do this are for python 2.x and do not transfer over to python 3. I'd like to be able to call a function which will automatically update the progress of the bar. I.E. myBar.updateProgress(76) where myBar is the current progressBar object and 76% would be the distance the progress bar is to completion. If someone could help me with this that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so far or why it cannot transfer over to Python 3?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it took a while but I got this working.

I don't know what you encountered that was not compatiable with Python 3.x but I found this newer video that I followed.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cvBRhYeO7hc

It worked almost perfectly apart from the "stop" command which I could not get to work.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time

root = Tk()
root.title('Progress Bar')
root.geometry("640x400")

def run():
  progressBar['maximum'] = 100
  for i in range(101):
    time.sleep(0.05)
    progressBar["value"] = i
    progressBar.update()
    progressBar["value"] = 0

buttonFrame = LabelFrame(text="Progress Bar")
buttonFrame.grid(column=0,row=0)

button1 = Button(buttonFrame, text="Run Progress Bar",command=run)
button1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

progressBar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient="horizontal", length=286,mode="determinate")
progressBar.grid(column = 0, row = 3, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Try picking that apart, if it is not what you wanted I would need your own code to figure out what you were thinking about.

It seems to throw an error when exited prematurely but nothing that cannot be fixed with a excerpt.

EDIT: I just realized you want to be able to edit it with a function, this should work:

```
def update_prog(v):
  progressBar["value"] = v
```

(I have not tested this but it should work, if you remove the RUN function, and make sure to have progressBar["maximum"] = X somewhere then it will be fine.